# Show that if the 0-functional is the only linear bounded functional that is 0 on a set, the set is dense

Tags: functional-analysis, dual-spaces

I want to show that

$$(\forall f\in X^*: f|_F \equiv 0 \Rightarrow f\equiv 0) \Leftrightarrow F \text{ dense in }X.$$

I have proven the direction $\Leftarrow$.
But I have problems with the other direction.
If this direction does hold, we could equivalently show that if $F$ is not dense in $X$ the other statement doesn't hold.

If I just think of finding an $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ that has to be continuous and $f|_F \equiv 0$ this is simple. Since $\bar{F} \neq X$ and $\bar{F}$ closed it holds that $\emptyset \neq X \setminus \bar{F}$ open and so we can construct a continuous functional that is not $0$ in an open ball around an $x\in X \setminus \bar{F}$.

However such a functional $f$ obviously has not to be linear. And for example in the case of $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $F=\mathbb{Z}$ there doesn't even exist such a functional.

So I don't really have an idea to prove this direction. I'm thankful for any hints on this.

Comment: This is true if you  assume that $F$ is a vector sub-space of $X$ but you have not said so. Please edit.

Comment: This is false if  $F$ is any arbitrary  subset of $X.$  For example if $F$ is the closed unit ball of $X$ then $F$ is not dense in $X$ (unless $X=\{0\}$) but  $f|_{F}=0$ iff $ f=0 .$